# Parse error on portrait media query - wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

I'm building my first responsive Wordpress theme, but getting my media query for portrait has stopped working when I've converted the static HTML to a theme. The weird thing is that the portrait query worked fine as a static site.

This is my code:

```
@media all and (orientation: portrait) {

            #main {
                display: table;
                max-width: 100%;
                        }

            #content img {
                                width:100%;
                                height:auto;
                                display: table-cell;
                                vertical-align: middle
                            }

             #tabbtn {
                        width:20%;
                        min-width: 30px;
             }

}
```

& this is the error that shows up on the W3C validation check:

```
Parse Error [ @media all and (orientation: portrait)]
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, for anyone looking - the actual error was the fact that the image wasn't responding to my fluid CSS (due to Wordpress adding fixed height/width). I didn't realise this before. The parse error, I think, was irrelevant.

Currently now trying to solve the problem with the info here: http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/getting-wordpress-play-nice-responsive-images